# Proof verification: Continuous function with specified values on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, continuity

Suppose $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(0)=1$, and $f(x)$ is a rational number for every $x \in [0, 1]$. Prove that $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f(x) \neq 1$ for all $x \in (0, 1]$. Note that the codomain is the set of real numbers, so we use the fact that between two rationals, there is at least one real number, meaning there are gaps in the line, i.e., given $\varepsilon>0$, $\nexists \delta>0$ such that if $|x-p|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(p)|<\varepsilon$. This is a contradiction, given that $f$ is continuous for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Therefore, $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Translate to English:

I would like a rigorous proof of this. Is mine good?

Comment: Not clear at all. What do you mean by "there are gaps in the line"? Why $\delta$ doesn't exist, and for which $\epsilon$? And what is the point $p$? I don't understand you idea at all. Hint: To solve the exercise, use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things here that don't really work, but it seems to me like you have the right idea.

The first thing you're doing is saying "Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f(x)\neq1$ for all $x\in(0,1]$". This is not what you want to contradict. Indeed if this led to a contradiction, then what you would have proven would be that $f(x)=1$ for *some* $x\in(0,1]$; the negation of

$$\forall x\in A:P(x)$$

is

$$\exists x\in A:\neg P(x).$$

So what you should start with is supposing that $f(x)\neq 1$ for *some* $x\in(0,1]$.

Next up, I really don't see what you mean by the rest. In particular, I think you have the right idea here, but you're not really presenting it in a clear way. If I understand you correctly, you want to use that between any two rationals there is an *irrational* (note: you also wrote real, but the reals include the rationals as well), and then have this contradict continuity.

Let's take your idea and write it into a clearer and fully rigorous proof:

Suppose for a contradiction that $f(x)\neq1$ for some $x\in(0,1]$. As every interval in $\mathbb{R}$ contains an irrational number, we can find some irrational number $\xi$ strictly between $1$ and $f(x)$. But now as $f$ is continuous, then by the intermediate value theorem $f$ has to attain $\xi$ on the interval $(0,x)$, i.e. $f(y)=\xi$ for some $y\in(0,x)$. But this contradicts that $f$ only attains rational values, and so the claim follows.